Existence of global minimum of convex function
Let $f:I\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a convex function cotinous on a interval $I$.
If $f$ not is monotone, then is true that $f$ has a global minimum in inner of $I$?
--
My attempt: because $f$ is no monotone exists $x_1<x_2<x_3$ with $f(x_1)>f(x_2)<f(x_3)$.
Because $f$ is continuous on $[x_1,x_3]$ exists a point of minimum $x_0$ on $[x_1,x_3]$.  The point $x_0$ is distinct from $x_1$ and $x_3$ and $x_0\in\overset{\circ}{I}$.
My intuiction says thats $x_0$ is a minimum global of $f$. How can proofs this? It's for exemple true that $f$ is increasing for $x>x_3$ e decreasing for $x<x_1$?

By monotone do you mean strictly monotone, or do you allow for constant bits?

$f$ is monotone if is increasing [$x<y$ implies $f(x)\le f(y)$] or decreasing.

For convex functions, local minimizers are global.

monotone or not does not matter in this case

Suppose $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ is a convex function, then $f$ is continuous on $I$. Since $f$ is not monotone, then there exist $a,b,c\in I$ with $c\in [a,b]$ such that
$$
  (f(a)-f(c))\cdot(f(b)-f(c))>0.
$$
By convexity of $f$, one gets $f(c)<\min\{f(a),f(b)\}$. Since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, there exists a minimum point $x_0$ of $f$ on $[a,b]$. Define
$$\begin{aligned}
  I_{l} =&\ \{x\in I:\ x\le x_0 \mbox{ and } f(y)\ge f(x_0)\mbox{ for any }y\in[x,x_0]\},\\
  I_{r} =&\ \{x\in I:\ x\ge x_0 \mbox{ and } f(y)\ge f(x_0)\mbox{ for any }y\in[x_0,x]\}.
\end{aligned}$$
Set $m=\inf I_{l}$ and $M=\sup I_{r}$. It suffices to prove that $m,M\notin\mathring{I}$.
If not, assume $m\in\mathring{I}$, by continuity of $f$, we have $f(m)=f(x_0)$. Since $f$ is convex, one gets $f\equiv f(x_0)$ on $[m,x_0]$. Hence, we have $a<m$ since $f\ge f(x_0)$ in $[a,b]$ and $f(a)>f(c)\ge f(x_0)$. By the definition of $m$, there exists some piont $x_1\in(a,m)$ such that $f(x_1)<f(x_0)$, which leads to a contradiction with the minimality of $x_0$ on $[a,b]$. Hence, $m\notin\mathring{I}$. Similarly, it is proved that $M\notin\mathring{I}$.
